# Configuration for multi-step parallel stages

Tags: drone.io

I have a mono-repo that contains multiple services. Ideally, I want to test each service in parallel. Each branch has 2 stages:

- test
- benchmark

To give something similar to this:

```
           clone
          /    \
         /      \
        /        \
       /          \
  svc1-test    svc2-test
      |            |
  svc1-bench   svc2-bench
      \            /
       \          /
        \        /
         \      /
          notify
```

The build would pass only if the all branches have succeeded. Furthermore, we could fail a branch early and not execute the benchmarking if the tests fail for any given branch.

From reading the documentation I see how I can run parallel stages using `group`, but not how to put many stages in a single branch.

I guess my fallback solution would be to put combine test+benchmark in a single stage, but I think it would be nice to isolate them, especially since the dependencies may vary for each.

Comment: Why not having a group for `test` and a group for `bench`? tests will run in parallel, and you will fail fast if any test fails, then run the benchmarks. The effect seems to be almost the same.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar and found it answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53005152/8895640) by the user [cdieck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1683870/cdieck).

[This is how it looks in Blue Ocean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxuAA.png)

Copying the same for quick reference:

```
pipeline {
   agent none
   stages {
      stage("Example") {
         failFast true
         parallel {
            stage("win7-vs2012") {
               agent {
                  label "win7-vs2012"
               }
               stages {
                  stage("checkout (win7-vs2012)") {
                     steps {
                        echo "win7-vs2012 checkout"
                     }
                  } 

                  stage("build (win7-vs2012)") {
                     steps {
                        echo "win7-vs2012 build"
                     }
                  }

                  stage("test (win7-vs2012)") {
                     steps {
                        build 'test-win7-vs2012'
                     }
                  }
               } 
            }

            stage("win10-vs2015") {
               agent {
                  label "win10-vs2015"
               }
               stages {
                  stage("checkout (win10-vs2015)") {
                     steps {
                        echo "win10-vs2015 checkout"
                     }
                  } 

                  stage("build (win10-vs2015)") {
                     steps {
                        echo "win10-vs2015 build"
                     }
                  }

                  stage("test (win10-vs2015)") {
                     steps {
                        build 'test-win10-vs2015'
                     }
                  }
               } 
            }

            stage("linux-gcc5") {
               agent {
                  label "linux-gcc5"
               }
               stages {
                  stage("checkout (linux-gcc5)") {
                     steps {
                        echo "linux-gcc5 checkout"
                     }
                  } 

                  stage("build (linux-gcc5)") {
                     steps {
                        echo "linux-gcc5 build"
                     }
                  }

                  stage("test (linux-gcc5)") {
                     steps {
                        build 'test-linux-gcc5'
                     }
                  }
               } 
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```